# Example of union of closures that is a proper subset of the closure of the union

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $A_j, j\in J$ be a family of subsets of a topologic space $X$. Show that $\cup_j \overline{A_j} \subset \overline{\cup_j A_j}$ and show an example where it's a proper subset.

I thought in $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $A_n = \left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right), n\in \mathbb{N}$. So we have 
$$
\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\overline{A_n} = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right] = (0,1]
$$
and
$$
\overline{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n} = \overline{(0,1)-\{1/n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}} = [0,1]
$$
Is this right? The last equality I think is due to every $1/n$ being a limit point of the union of the intervals $A_n$. But I don't see how to prove this much properly, so I don't know if my example is right. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where does the $(0,1)-\{1/n \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ come from? I don't understand that part, but everything else is correct.

Comment: $$\begin{align} A_i \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j} A_j,\ \text {for all}\ i. \\ \implies \overline {A_i} \subseteq \overline {\bigcup\limits_{j} A_j},\ \text {for all}\ i. \\ \implies \bigcup\limits_{j} \overline {A_j} \subseteq \overline {\bigcup\limits_{j} A_j}. \end{align}$$

Comment: For the converse observe that $$\begin{align} A_j \subseteq \overline {A_j},\ \text{for all}\ j. \\ \implies \bigcup\limits_{j} A_j \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j} \overline{A_j}. \\ \implies \overline {\bigcup\limits_{j} A_{j}} \subseteq \overline {\bigcup\limits_{j} \overline {A_{j}}} \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j} \overline {A_{j}}. \end{align}$$

Comment: So in order to find the counter example you need to find a collection of sets $\{A_j \}$ in a topological space such that $\bigcup\limits_{j} \overline {A_{j}}$ is not closed. Clearly then the collection should be infinite. Since $(0,1]$ is not a closed subset of $\Bbb R$ with usual topology your example is perfectly fine to me.

Comment: In your example $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \Bbb N} A_{n} = (0,1).$ So $\overline {\bigcup\limits_{n \in \Bbb N} A_{n}} = [0,1].$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a bijection $\varphi : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$.

For each $j \in \mathbb{N}$, let $A_j = \lbrace \varphi(j) \rbrace$. For the usual topology on $X = \mathbb{R}$, $A_j$ is closed as a single point. So 
$$\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{A_j} = \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \lbrace \varphi(j) \rbrace = \mathbb{Q}$$

But
$$\overline{\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} A_j } = \overline{ \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \lbrace \varphi(j) \rbrace} = \overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$$